Can't log out of Blazor WebAssembly client app
In a fresh Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App (dotnet new blazorwasm --auth Individual), I updated the call to AddOidcAuthentication() to add Google authentication:
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    // Configure your authentication provider options here.
    // For more information, see https://aka.ms/blazor-standalone-auth
    builder.Configuration.Bind("Local", options.ProviderOptions);

    options.ProviderOptions.Authority = "https://accounts.google.com/";
    options.ProviderOptions.RedirectUri = "https://localhost:7167/authentication/login-callback";
    options.ProviderOptions.PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:7167/authentication/logout-callback";
    options.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = "id_token";

    options.ProviderOptions.ClientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID");
});

I am able to log in successfully (I get a token saved in SessionStorage and see that it knows my name), but when I log out, it doesn't "stick". The token is deleted, but when I refresh the page, the token reappears and the app treats me as logged in again. (I'm just using the default code to log in and out.)
Am I doing something wrong that's preventing my logout from "sticking"? Or am I misunderstanding something about Google authentication?
Repo here (but I literally didn't change anything except the code I posted).

Did you ever solve this? I've got exactly the same issue. NavigateToLogout removes the token from SessionStorage, and then almost immediately does an authentication check against my external identity provider, which retrieves a fresh token. I have also tried setting returnUrl to go to my provider's explicit logout endpoint, but that's not making any difference. I still see the token in SessionState disappear and reappear.

@jonathan , I have not found a resolution for this.

I have found a resolution to this for my external identity provider (not Google). What I found was happening was:
I was calling Navigation.NavigateToLogout("authentication/logout", "https://myExternalIdP/logoutPath");

logout (authentication/logout) will clear the JWT from session state (good)
the blazor WASM app would then (could never figure out what precisely was calling this) immediately try to figure out my authentication state, which would immediately make a call to my IdP and get a fresh JWT and persist it in session state (bad).
the blazor WASM app would redirect to my IdP logout path, invalidating my session with my IdP (good).

This means that I still have a valid-looking JWT in the app. A subsequent, second logout would properly clear everything. This is because step 2, where the blazor app was trying to figure out my authentication state, would receive an error from IdP and not get a fresh JWT, but only on the second 'logout'.
How I worked around it
My external IdP, as noted, has a logout endpoint that also accepts a return_url querystring parameter. When the user clicks on logout:

Navigate to the IdP logout endpoint, with a redirect back to a new logout page in my app (ie Navigation.NavigateTo($"https://myExternalIdP/logoutPath?return_url={Navigation.BaseUri}logout");
IdP logs out my session and redirects back to a new page in my Blazor WASM app
In OnInitialized on my new logout page, call Navigation.NavigateToLogout("authentication/logout", "/");
This allows the framework to set state / remove JWT as expected, and the check for authentication state against the external IdP fails.

Basically just ensure that the correct order of operations is carried out.
It feels like this should exist in the framework, so I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this, but it is working as expected.
